# c++ compile and run in linux

Tags: c++, linux, pointers, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined reference to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569399/undefined-reference-to)

In my directory I have:

```
main.cpp
tree.cpp
tree.h
```

I have included tree.h in main.cpp

```
#include "tree.h"
```

then in my main function I write

```
tree* t=new tree()
```

For compiling I will do

```
g++ main.cpp
```

but I have the error

```
undefined reference to `tree::tree()'
```

what's the problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: try to avoid `tree* t=new tree()`, that's Java-ish, and neither necessary nor efficient nor memory-safe. Just make it `tree t;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to compile and link Tree source code as well:

```
$ g++ -c -o tree.o tree.cpp
$ g++ -o test main.cpp tree.o
```

run your application:

```
$ ./test
```

Comment: Can you explain what does above code do?I am new to it.

Comment: you need a good gcc manual  http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/ref/gcc-intro.html

Comment: @sweet Basically, what happens it that you need to make the object files for both the tree and main files. The first line creates the object file for tree.cpp, the second line is creating the object file for main.cpp and linking it to the object file for tree.cpp, which then creates the executable file.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to create yourself a make file for that.
A make file would automate the compilation of multiple files programs.

For example, you could create a file "makefile" containing the lines suggested by billz.

```
all:
    g++ -c -o tree.o tree.cpp
    g++ -o test main.cpp tree.o
```

Then, running `make` from the terminal in the makefile's folder would execute the `all` section.

For more information on makefiles, see http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/writing-makefiles/

I haven't tested the above code, it's possible that some tweaking would be necessary.

Comment: But I do suggest to have a much better `makefile`, with real dependencies and *make* variables.

Comment: Of course! The above is given only as an example. The link gives plenty of info on how to create a better makefile

Answer (score 0):

Put the header guard, something like this

```
#ifndef NAME_H
#define NAME_H

//your codes

#endif
```

Comment: does it work? I have that problem before as well and that solved it.

note that NAME_H can be anything as long as both are the same.

Comment: It was not my problem actually. My problem was linking of objects in g++